# Currying and mapStateToProps in React

Tags: reactjs, redux, currying

So I'm trying to get a bit better with CS concepts. Going over the concept of currying. This seems to be pretty similar to what is going on with redux/react when you connect. Is it correct to call this currying? If I understand correctly, connect returns a second function which then takes App as an argument.... that's currying, right?

(Take pity on me, I'm trying to understand the concept)

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  results: state.results ? state.results.items : []
}); 

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

Comment: Yes, the connect function is indeed an example of a curried function. Reference this question for more insight: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Not quite.

I'm willing to be wrong about this, but a curried function will return a function that accepts the remaining arguments when invoked with fewer than the required number of arguments.

`connect()` is not curried by default. This means invoking it without any arguments does not produce a partially applied function. Instead, it will give you a valid higher-order component that provides `dispatch` to your component.